# Cakephp 3.2.6 admin prefix - Error: The application is trying to load a file from the Admin plugin

Tags: html, cakephp

I am struggling from the migration of my 2.0 cakephp site to 3.2.6. I followed the cookboo on how to implement an admin section of my site. When link to my admin section I receive: Error: The application is trying to load a file from the Admin plugin. Below are my codes:

\config\routes.php

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
// All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
// And have the prefix => admin route element added.
$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

\src\Controller\Admin

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
* Quads Controller
*
* @property \App\Model\Table\QuadsTable $Quads
*/
class QuadsController extends AppController
{

/**
 * Index method
 *
 * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Categories', 'Genres', 'Venues']
    ];
    $quads = $this->paginate($this->Quads);

    $this->set(compact('quads'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['quads']);
}
```

All of my .ctp files are in \Template\Admin.

Comment: what url are you trying to load?

Comment: /quadzer/admin/quads

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp 3 now requires themes to be in the plugin folder. The culprit code in my AppController.php was:

```
 if ((isset($this->request->prefix) && ($this->request->prefix == 'admin'))) 
{
$this->theme = 'admin';
}
```